# Error type - 2: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing )

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have following error:

Error type - 2: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 25: in /var/www/hosting/com/galerielaboratorio/scripts/functions.php on line 766

Here is the function:

```
function getThumbName($photo, $name = 'thumb') {

$ext = preg_replace ("/.*\./", "", $photo);
$photo = preg_replace ("/\.". $ext ."$/", "" , $photo). "." . $name . "." .$ext; // this line causes the error  

return $photo;
```

}

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot read your expression, but you missed one `)`. `()`-pairs define expression groups. One `(` without its corresponding `)` is just invalid (and thats what the error message tries to tell you). If you want to have a literal `(` you must escape it `\(`

However, have a look at `pathinfo()`, `explode()` and `str_replace()`. This is not a scenario for regular expressions

```
$ext = pathinfo($photo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$photo = basename($photo) . '.' . $name . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where it goes wrong; it's not clear from the code, as you're building a dynamic regular expression. Anyway, here's an alternative for you to enjoy, which contains slightly more error checking than your original function.

```
<?php
function getThumbName($photo, $name = 'thumb') {
    if( $ext = getExtension( $photo ) ) {
        return basename( $photo, $ext ) . 'thumb.' . $ext;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns the file extension if it exists, false otherwise.
 * @param string $filename
 * @return string|bool
 */
function getExtension( $filename ) {
    return pathinfo( $filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
}

echo getThumbName( 'foo.jpg' ) . PHP_EOL; // foo.thumb.jpg
echo getThumbName( 'slightly.more.complex.gif' ) . PHP_EOL; // slightly.more.complex.thumb.gif

echo getThumbname( 'This is where it gets interesting' ) . PHP_EOL; // false.
```